# Why I'm getting outofrange exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code in a `DoWork` event of a `backgroundworker`:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        WaitHandle[] waitHandleList = null;
        List<ManualResetEvent> mre = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

        for (int i = 0; i < GetProcessesIntptrList().Count; i++)
        {
            ProcessInfo info;
            info = GetProcessInfo(GetProcessesIntptrList()[i]);
            if (procList.Count == GetProcessesIntptrList().Count)
                break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < procList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 9)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                SafeWaitHandle swh1 = new SafeWaitHandle(procList[i].Handle, false);

                mre[i]    = new ManualResetEvent(true);
                mre[i].SafeWaitHandle = swh1;
                waitHandleList = new WaitHandle[] { mre[i] };
                worker.ReportProgress(0, "Running");
            }
        }

        while (true)
        {
                    if (procList != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < procList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandleList);
                            if (procList[i].HasExited)
                            {
                                worker.ReportProgress(0, "Exited");
                                procList[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }

    }
```

And on the line:

```
mre[i]    = new ManualResetEvent(true);
```

An exception of type `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` occurred in `mscorlib.dll` but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

When the exception happen mre is empty count 0 and I is also 0
The question is how can I create then 9 instances of the mre ?

Comment: Mre is empty when you first try to access it.

Comment: if i is 0 then it will be trying to access the first element in mre...which doesn't exist if it's empty. So it's out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question, it's difficult, if not impossible to know what the best solution is. However, it's likely that all you need to do is change the assignment from this:

```
mre[i]    = new ManualResetEvent(true);
```

to this:

```
mre.Add(new ManualResetEvent(true));
```

Comment: @ManuelSpechia that is a different question; you might want to post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You're using object mre as a list of ManualResetEvent, which does not have a fixed size with located location for items.
So the code mre[i] with list does not reached that index 'i' is not allowed and will throw an IndexOutOfRangeExeption
So you have to add element using add method and then you can access that element via index.
A bag is different than a hole tray.